# Why does my Java dice game keep repeating its roll?

Tags: java

I have made a Dice game in Java using two files. The code runs perfectly, but it seems to have a logical error in it that I don't understand. In the game, it only outputs the same value as the previous roll. So if the die rolled a 6 and you rolled again, it would say you rolled a 6 again continuously. I'm trying to fix it currently but am having trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here are the two programs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceGameTest {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declare instance variables
        int choice = 0;
        //int total;
        //total = die1.getRoll() + die2.getRoll();

        //create the 2 die
        Dice die1 = new Dice();
        //Dice die2 = new Dice();

        //print out description of game
        System.out.println("Welcome to Eric and John's Dice game!");
        System.out.println("This dice game is very simple, here are the rules!");
        System.out.println("    1. Roll a die");
        System.out.println("    2. To win, you must get a 4 or higher");
        System.out.println("    3. Have Fun!\n");

        //ask the user if they want to roll the dice or quit
        System.out.println("Would you like to roll the die to start playing? Press 1 to roll or \"-1\" to quit");
        //user's choice
        choice = input.nextInt();

        //if the user puts 1
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            System.out.printf("You rolled a %d%n", die1.getRoll());
        }

        //play the game
        do
        {
            die1.getRoll();
            if(die1.getRoll() >= 4)
            {
                System.out.println("Hooray! You won by getting a: " + die1.getRoll());
            }
            else if(die1.getRoll() < 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Too Bad! Your roll was: " + die1.getRoll() + " and it was not greater than or equal to 4");
                }
            //ask the user if they want to roll the dice again or quit
            System.out.println("Would you like to roll the die to start playing? Press 1 to roll or \"-1\" to quit");
            //user's choice
            choice = input.nextInt();

        }while(choice != -1);

        if(choice == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("You Quit the Game!");
        }
    }
}
```

And this

```
 import java.util.Random; //class used to generate random number for dice roll

 public class Dice {
     private int numberSides;
     private Random randomGenerator;
     private int currentRoll;

     //default constructor
     Dice() {
         randomGenerator = new Random(); //initialize random object
         numberSides = 6; //default number of sides
         currentRoll =  randomGenerator.nextInt(numberSides)+1; //initialize roll (1-6)
     }

     public int getRoll() {
        return currentRoll;
    }

//"roll" a random integer between 1 and numberSides
    public void roll() {
        currentRoll =  randomGenerator.nextInt(numberSides)+1; //reroll 1-6
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you roll?

Comment: With the way you have it currently, your die assigns a random value to its Roll variable only when it's created and in function roll() (which I think is never called). What you could do is call the roll() function when you can a getRoll() function, or create a new separate Die every time a player is rolling it (wouldn't advise it).

Comment: How would I go about calling the roll()function a getRoll() function? Could you please specify?

Comment: Just add the line "roll();" (no quotations) before the return in your getRoll() function, and that should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you just keep calling die1.getRoll at the beginning of your loop.  That number is not changing unless you call roll.

Remove currentRoll from your constructor.  You don't need to put it there. Then,

```
die1.getRoll()
```

Should be,

```
die1.roll()
```

In your do while loop like this

```
  do
    {
        die1.roll();
        if(die1.getRoll() >= 4)
        {
            System.out.println("Hooray! You won by getting a: " +     die1.getRoll());
        }
        else if(die1.getRoll() < 4)
        //rest of it
```

Alternatively, you could make a few modifications in your game and change your function.

```
public int getRoll()
{
    roll();
    return currentRoll;
}
```

Comment: I fear the way you wrote it is too confusing. All he has to do is return the value generated in the method `roll()` instead of assigning it to the variable and then exchange the method call from `getRoll()` to `roll()` in his loop.
Also I would suggest the OP to not call the method so many times but instead assign it to a variable in the loop and work with that.

Comment: I don't see how this is confusing

Comment: I wrote the comment before you edited your answer. Now it's already better

Comment: The only reason I suggested the other way was because if you have a die you literally have to roll it (in real life).  So why "roll" it in the constructor then roll it again.  It is far more intuitive to say die.roll() to roll it and die.getroll() to get the roll.  That's why I put it like this

Comment: Sure and I don't disagree with that at all. I would just remove the method `getRoll()` completely and let the method `roll()` directly return the result. But that's just something to argue about and your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does my Java dice game keep repeating its roll?

You keep getting the same random number because the only code which is responsible for generating a new random number lies in the constructor of your Dice class.

The constructor will only be invoked **once** upon instantiation. Calling `getRoll()` subsequently will just return you the same random number.

If you want to receive a new random number from `getRoll()`, you can do it as:

```
public int getRoll(){    //return a new dice roll every time
    return (randomGenerator.nextInt(numberSides)+1);
}
```

If you like the Dice class to "remember" the current roll, you can have a method like:

```
public int roll(){    //return a new dice roll every time & save current
    currentRoll =  randomGenerator.nextInt(numberSides)+1;
    return currentRoll;
}
```

> How would I go about calling the roll()function a getRoll() function? Could you please specify?

You don't need both `roll()` and `getRoll()`, either one is enough to generate a new random number. You just have to make sure you are placing `randomGenerator.nextInt(numberSides)+1` in your `roll()` or `getRoll()` method to make it work.

Comment: @BeenisProgramming Take a look a my solution